# Rejecting Post-Internship Offer

Tags: internship, fulltime

Need an opinion on my current situation.

Back to January 2021,I applied for an internship at Company A. I got the position and they gave me contract stating that I have to accept a full time position with the company 'when offered during the internship or upon the completion of the internship'. This contract is only effective until 30th June 2021

Throughout the internship, the company have been hinting about a full time position but never really offered me one officially. 30th June 2021 was my last day and yet I didn't get an official offer yet.

So I applied to Company B in August. while I was waiting for response from Company B, Company A got in touch through a phone call (also in August) asking if I am interested to work for Company A (since I didn't have an option then, I said yes), However, they didn't make this official yet,they haven't ask me to sign a new contract or discuss the employment terms etc.

As time passes by, Company B which I applied to got back to me and offered me the position I was applying for. I really feel that Company B is a good fit for me as the position is more related to my skills and interest, they also offered me a higher pay and more benefits+stability as Company B is bigger and more stable.

However, I feel guilty to break the news to Company A as I have signed the initial contract (although it has expired) and gave my word to Company A that I was interested (although through phone call)

So I am wondering if it is bad for me to reject the offer from Company A when they finally gave me an official offer? Or am I obliged to accept their offer as the overdue contract I signed back then said I should accept their offer? Is it possible for me to go to Company B? If yes, what should I do to Company A?

UPDATE: Thank you all for your responses and encouragement. I have decided to work for Company B and will clarify my decision with Company A. Once again, thank you!

Comment: Your question title doesn't really match its body: there's no mention of an offer in it. "Asking if I am interested to work for Company A" is _not_ an offer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An expired contract is just that, EXPIRED!  Don't feel guilty, if Company A wanted to hire you they had adequate opportunity.

At this point do what you think is best for your career.  If you like Company B and the job is in line with your career goals, then accept that offer.

Based on what you've said, I see no reason to feel obligated to Company A.

Answer (score 8):

Don't feel guilty, early birds and all that.

If your internship company really wanted you they would've made you an offer.  As it is, the second company seems like a better fit, a better offer, and they actually got up and made one.  Take the new job offer, thank Company A for your time there, and move on with your career.

Answer (score -3):

1. You have nothing from anyone until you have a written, signed, offer
2. You mention "guilt". This would be like one of the cows I eat in a hamburger having "guilt" about something it did to me.
3. The original contract with "A" just sounds **whacky**. They can't "obligate you to take" some future offer.  It is so bizarre it is meaningless.
4. "will clarify my decision with Company A" never, ever, ever, ever offer any information - ever - of any type - to any company. Simply reply "no thanks".  ABSOLUTELY do not tell them why, ABSOLUTELY do not mention any other companies you are considering or going to join. Say nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I haven't talk to Company A yet. I want to keep my reasonings to myself for not coming back to Company A, but my boss at Company A is quite push-y (which is one of the reasons I haven't follow up with them), hence I thought of clarifying why, but if there is an option to keep her from asking questions, I would, I'm just wondering if there's a way to tell her that I won't be working with her company without her prying too much about my future plans